# How to use Spring cache Manager with redis 1.6.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

We are using `Spring Cache Manager` with `spring-data-redis` `1.5.2`. These days we want to upgrade `spring-data-redis` to latest release i.e:1.6.2.RELEASE.

For some weird reason everything works good with `1.5.2` but when upgrading to `1.6.2` we get

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-cache.xml]:  Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
>   [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations]: Ambiguous
>   constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean
>   references as constructor arguments?

This message seems like a mistake as `redisTemplate` is `RedisTemplate` which implements `RedisOperations`.

Any idea how to solve it?

#### P.S

note that when removing the `cache configuration` the `1.6.2` version seems to work good. So the issue is with the cache.

#### Configuration

#### web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-redis.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring-cache.xml 
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

#### spring-redis.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher" />

    <!-- end of seesion managment configuration -->

    <bean id="redisConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
        <property name="port" value="${app.redis.port}" />
        <property name="hostName" value="${app.redis.hostname}" />
        <property name="password" value="${app.redis.password}" />
        <property name="usePool" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- for publishing string over redis channels -->
    <bean id="stringRedisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- for storing object into redis key,value -->
    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

#### spring-cache.xml

```
<!-- This file must load after spring-redis.xml -->
 <cache:annotation-driven /> 

<!-- declare Redis Cache Manager -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
    c:template-ref="redisTemplate" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the reason for this bug is that `RedisCacheManager` has two `constructors`. Both of them has `RedisOperations` as parameter. Forsome reason `Spring` couldnot understand its related to the `first constructor` and not to the second one. a work around is mention `constructor-arg` `index`

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="redisTemplate"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading from Spring Data Redis 1.5.2.RELEASE to 1.6.2.RELEASE, we need to use the below config for RedisCacheManager. Previous releases were using **redis-template-ref** instead of **redis-operations-ref**.

```
<beans:bean id='cacheManager'
        class='org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager'
        c:redis-operations-ref='redisTemplate'>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. Very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for those who reach this page.

```html
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager" factory-method="create" c:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory" p:transaction-aware="true" />

<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:host-name="${cache.redis.host}" p:port="${cache.redis.port}" p:use-pool="true">
  <constructor-arg ref="jedisPoolConfig"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig" p:maxTotal="${cache.redis.pool.maxTotal}" p:maxIdle="${cache.redis.pool.maxIdle}" p:maxWaitMillis="${cache.redis.pool.maxWaitMillis}" p:testOnBorrow="true" />
```